# How does Furious Focus combine with Reckless Rage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, rage

Does Furious Focus remove the attack penalty incurred from a Reckless Rage, which may or may not be similar/the same as Power Attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Furious Focus does not remove the penalties from Reckless Rage

[Reckless Rage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/reckless-rage/) says *when you use Power Attack*, you take an additional penalty, but does not say that it adjusts the penalty from [Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat-final):

> Benefit: **When you use Power Attack while raging or while using raging song, you take an additional –1 penalty** on melee attack rolls and combat maneuver checks, and you gain an additional +2 bonus on melee damage rolls. Modify this damage bonus appropriately based on the type of weapon you are using, as normal for Power Attack.

This means that this penalty is not optional and applies whenever you use [Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat-final) combined with [Rage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Barbarian/#TOC-Rage-Ex-) or [Raging Song](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald/#TOC-Raging-Song-Su-).

While [Furious Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/furious-focus-combat) only requires you to **use** Power Attack and wield weapons two-handed to apply it's effects. But it only removes the penalties from Power Attack and no other feats:

> Benefit: When you are wielding a two-handed weapon or a one-handed weapon with two hands, and **using the Power Attack feat**, you do not suffer **Power Attack’s penalty** on melee attack rolls on the first attack you make each turn. You still suffer the penalty on any additional attacks, including attacks of opportunity.

You can see clearly that Furious Focus affects Power Attack's penalty, and if Reckless Rage was supposed to also affect this penalty, it would (or should) use a similar wording. But you can never know for sure, since they were most likely written by different authors.

If I can advise you, do not take that feat, its inferior to *many* options to increase your damage and it costs a full feat for the effect of a fraction of Power Attack. Basically, all this feat does is to count your character level as 4 higher to define the effects of Power Attack.

Considering this, it isn't unthinkable to allow Furious Focus to also apply its effects to Reckless Rage, in order to improve the feat a little bit. It will only affect the very first attack each round and it will cost the character three feats.

Comment: Does the feat gain in power if you go down the Vital Strike line and add in the two-handed Fighter archetype ability Overhand Chop? I also have an 18 STR at the moment, 22 when Raging.

Comment: The feat does not improve by itself, your character might, regardless if you take the feat or not. Both options you mentioned are better alternatives than this feat. Note that Im not saying its a *bad* feat, but that there are better feats to invest if you are already investing your *third* feat for your character.

Comment: can you open up a discussion so we can discuss these various other feats?

Comment: @FrancisJohn extra rage power will most likely always be better than -1 to hit/+2 to damage. And if you will multiclass fighter, its worth noting that fighter 4 is the requirement for weapon specialization (flat +2 to damage). If you are not playing the unchained barbarian, the Raging Vitality feat is a must, so you make sure you dont die automatically when you hit 0 hp.